# .net compiler - binary compare of exe files

Tags: .net, windows-7, compiler-construction, windows-xp, compare

Our main problem is that we can't make a binary compare of the exe files which are generated by the compiler.

We have three different machines in our company
1) Windows 7 64 Bit - .NET 4.0
2) Windows XP 32 Bit - .NET 4.0
3) Windows XP 32 Bit - .NET 4.0

All the projects are set to compile for a x86 architecture ... so therefore the exe is 32 Bit.


We have take a look the the il files later on and all of them (same project compiled on every machine) are swap a little bit ...

Is this a normal situation, that every mahine will generate a specific exe file, which is not compareable anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal; amongst other things, there is a module id that is different for every single build (this is separate from those set in your `AssemblyInfo`)

Comment: But when this is normal. How can I be sure that the binary from the xp is "funtional" the same like the one from the Win7 machine?

Comment: @element you may test the most suspicious parts of the code (for example, functions that use native code libraries). for me it seems like the simplest way